# Validation issue with MDM Zinc and the Apple App Store

Tags: mac-app-store, mdm-zinc

We're using MDM Zinc to create an app for the Apple App Store. Everything looks fine and the app runs on both 10.6 and 10.7 like it's supposed to. Everything appears to be set up fine on iTunesConnect. The last step before submission is using XCode to validate the archive. We get one error.

**The following issues were found during validation:**

`The application bundle contains a tool or framework Flash Player [Artic.app/Contents/Resources/Flash Player.plugin] using the bundle identifier 'com.macromedia.Flash Player.plugin', which is not a valid bundle identifier.`

Notice the space between the words Flash and Player. Spaces are not valid characters in bundle identifiers. 
Since MDM markets the product as a way to publish apps to the app store presumably there is a workaround.

So two questions. Does anyone know the workaround? And has anyone used Zinc and gotten an app approved in the app store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Apple changed the validation criteria. Zinc has issued an update and my projects now validate.